# If-else Refactor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, if-statement

I am trying to refactor this block of if else statements. What can be the best optimized version of this code?

```
`const handlePhoneNumberFormat = (rules, value, callback) => {
    if (value && value.match(phoneNumberRegex)) {
      if (value.includes('-')) {
        if (value.indexOf('-') === 2) {
          if (value.length !== 10) {
            callback('Please enter 7 digits after "-".');
          } else {
            callback();
          }
        } else if (value.indexOf('-') === 3) {
          if (value.length !== 14) {
            callback('Please enter 10 digits after "-".');
          } else {
            callback();
          }
        } else {
          callback();
        }
      } else {
        callback();
      }
    } else {
      callback('');
    }
  };`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one solution that probably works just as well as your code

```
const handlePhoneNumberFormat = (rules, value, callback) => {
    if (value && value.match(phoneNumberRegex)) {
        const pos = value.indexOf('-');
        const length = value.length;
        if (pos === 2 && length !== 10) {
            callback('Please enter 7 digits after "-".');
        } else if (pos === 3 && length !== 14) {
            callback('Please enter 10 digits after "-".');
        } else {
            callback():
        }
    } else {
      callback('');
    }
};
```

No repetition, each callback is unique ... though if you want smaller code

```
const handlePhoneNumberFormat = (rules, value, callback) => {
    const t = { "2": 10, "3": 14 };
    if (value && value.match(phoneNumberRegex)) {
        const pos = value.indexOf('-');
        const a = t[pos] || 0;
        if (a && a !== value.length) {
            callback(`Please enter ${a - pos - 1} digits after "-".')`);
        } else {
            callback():
        }
    } else {
      callback('');
    }
};
```

Though, not much smaller, and harder to read too

Answer (score 0):

You may still use if elses conditions but you have to combine some codes like

```
 value.indexOf('-') and value.includes('-') value && value.match(phoneNumberRegex)
```

and

```
value.indexOf('-') === 3 and value.length !== 14
```

to make your code shorter.

Answer (score 0):

One option you've got is to make use of the ternary operator in your function to define the value you are looking at passing:

```
    var returnValue;

    returnValue = (value && value.match(phoneNumberRegex) && value.includes('-')  && value.indexOf('-') === 2) ? 'Please enter 7 digits after "-".' : returnValue ;

    callback(returnValue);
```